# PIP Uninstall matplotlib error - Possible Versions or Dependency Issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pip, uninstallation

when I am trying to uninstall matplotlib on my Mac, I get the following error:

`$ sudo -H pip uninstall matplotlib`

```
Uninstalling matplotlib-1.3.1:  
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib  

  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7.egg-info  
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pylab.py  
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pylab.pyc  
Proceed (y/n)? y  
Exception:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 325, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 752, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 266, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors'
```

And a huge block of errors which follows that.

Also, on the flip-side, trying to upgrade matplotlib gives an error:

```
$ easy_install -U distribute    
$ sudo -H pip install --upgrade matplotlib  

Collecting matplotlib  
  Using cached matplotlib-1.5.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl  
Collecting numpy>=1.6 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached numpy-1.10.4-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl  
Collecting pytz (from matplotlib)  
  Using cached pytz-2015.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting python-dateutil (from matplotlib)  
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting cycler (from matplotlib)  
  Using cached cycler-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 (from matplotlib)    
  Using cached pyparsing-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil->matplotlib)  
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  
Installing collected packages: numpy, pytz, six, python-dateutil, cycler, pyparsing, matplotlib  
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1  
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.  
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:  
Exception:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 725, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 752, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 266, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)  
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-SAzqRB-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo -H pip install --upgrade matplotlib --ignore-installed numpy-1.8.0rc1`.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I have numpy version 1.10.4. When I changed the last part of your line to numpy-1.10.4rc1, it says:   `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement...`

Comment: @MichaelK see the error log you pasted, `DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.       Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:`. Did you try the command I posted?

Comment: Hi Rahul, I did try it but it gave me the same error.  What fixed this issue was: `brew reinstall python`

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped! I tried to install pyquil (pip install pyquil) and got "Operation not permitted" after a line that said "Uninstalling matplotlib-1.3.1". Uninstalling your way helped fixed the issue and install pyquil successfully.